# VS2010 Qt4 Designer Plugin linking with VS2010 Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, user-interface, qt4

I'm currently building my first QT4 interface using the add-in for VS2010, which all works fine. (Qt Application Project);

If I then create another project (QT4 Designer Plugin), create my custom widget and compile I can then move these files into  "$(QTDIR)\plugins\designer".

I can then use the designer to add this widget into my (Qt Application Project);

What I would like to know is is it possible debug a plugin? (Qt Designer will only load a release build on the QT4 Designer Plugin).
Can I change the directory QtDesigner looks in based on Release and Debug Build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about the designer. Create a debug .lib file for your plugin and use it while compiling your code. 
Just include the debug .lib file in your VIsual Studio (Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies). Ex: $(BUILDDIR)\Debug\myplugind.lib
And that should work. This works for me. Let me know if you see any issues.